# How to add a favicon to a static webpage made using parcel.js?

Tags: favicon, parceljs

I'm using parcel.js to build a basic static website (so HTML, CSS and front end JS only, but node / npm / parcel.js used for building).

I'd like to set a favicon. What's the best / simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At your `<head>` tag at your html file you can use

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: This worked for me, also in IE11 and behind reverse proxies / virtual directories. favicon.ico can go in the route directory: parcel puts it to dist on building.

Comment: (root directory even!)

Answer (score 1):

To have a `favicon.ico` that will be used as a *default* favicon by browsers, it needs to be present without the hash that parcel.js generates. For that, you would have to *not* include it anywhere as parcel will then generate the file with a hash, i.e. `favicon.f76ab27.ico`.

Try [parcel-plugin-static-files-copy](https://github.com/elwin013/parcel-plugin-static-files-copy) for this purpose. It copies files from one or more directories over to `dist`. Try the following settings in `package.json`:

```
{
  "staticFiles": {
    "staticPath": [
      {
        "staticPath": "path/to/static/files",
        "watcherGlob": "**"
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

> The trick is to **not define** a `staticPath`. Parcel will then copy the files to the *root* folder. All copied files will *not* have a hash appended.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add the [parcel-plugin-robot plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-plugin-robot) and add the favicon.ico file to the static/ directory.

This plugin will copy all files under `static/` to the root `dist/` directory, so this is also useful for robots.txt, humans.txt, browserconfig.xml and any other files that are expected at a website root directory by convention but that might not be referenced explicitly anywhere.